# How to subtract order amounts from budjet MVC 4 Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Given two tables, Project and Expense and fields

```
Project.ProjectKey
Project.Budget
Expense.ProjectKey
Expense.Amount
```

how would I write a Linq statement to give results that include `Project.Budget` minus all the `Expense.Amounts?`  How would I the reference that in an MVC 4 view?

Here is what I have...but it is not close:

```
var projects = from s in db.Project
               join d in db.Expense
               on s.ProjectKEY equals d.ProjectKEY
               select s;
```

Help is appreciated!

The View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TETS_DAL.Project>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Projects";
}

<h2>All Projects</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Project", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <!--@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectKEY)-->
            </th>
            <th>Project<br />
                Number
            </th>
            <th>Office
            </th>
            <th>Project<br />
                Description
            </th>
            <th>Start<br />
                Date
            </th>
            <th>End<br />
                Date
            </th>
            <th>Current<br />
                Period<br />
                Start
            </th>
            <th>Current<br />
                Period<br />
                End
            </th>
            <th>Total<br />
                Budget
            </th>
            <th>Total<br />
                Budget<br />
                Balance
            </th>
            <th>Current<br />
                Budget
            </th>
            <th>Current<br />
                Budget<br />
                Balance
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ProjectKEY)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Division.DivisionName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @String.Format("{0:d}", item.StartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @String.Format("{0:d}", item.OverallEndDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @String.Format("{0:d}", item.CurrentPeriodStartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @String.Format("{0:d}", item.CurrentPeriodEndDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OverallTechnologyBudget)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @*  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpenseItem.ExpenseAmount)*@
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentPeriodBudget)
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProjectKEY }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ProjectKEY }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Expenses", "Index", "ExpenseItem", new { projectSearchString = item.ProjectNumber }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    // Mock data
    var Project = new List<dynamic>
                      {
                          new { ProjectKey = 1, Budget = 500 },
                          new { ProjectKey = 2, Budget = 1000 },
                      };

    var Expense = new List<dynamic>
                      {
                          new { ProjectKey = 1, Amount = 10 },
                          new { ProjectKey = 1, Amount = 20 },
                          new { ProjectKey = 1, Amount = 30 },
                          new { ProjectKey = 2, Amount = 15 },
                          new { ProjectKey = 2, Amount = 25 },
                      };

    var data = (from p in Project
               join ex in Expense on p.ProjectKey equals ex.ProjectKey
               group ex by p into exgroup
               select new
               {
                   ProjectKey = exgroup.Key.ProjectKey,
                   Budget = exgroup.Key.Budget,
                   BudgetWithoutSumOfAmount = exgroup.Key.Budget - exgroup.Sum(g => g.Amount)
               }).ToList();

   // here you get in data variable list of objects:
   //
   //       [0] { ProjectKey = 1,
   //             Budget = 500,
   //             BudgetWithoutSumOfAmount = 440, }
   //       [1] { ProjectKey = 2,
   //             Budget = 1000,
   //             BudgetWithoutSumOfAmount = 960, }
```

Also you can get any other properties from `Project` with `exgroup.Key.PropertyName` in select statement.

Comment: Thank you.  This is very similar to something worked out in LinqPAD but couldn't get to work.  I'll compare the two in the morning.  In the meantime, how do you display the result in the Project view?  There are other fields in the Project table that need to be shown, too.  Will this affect them?

Comment: Look at updated answer. For displaying results you should pass it to your view with viewmodel, which can be filled from `data` list.

Comment: Query works in LinqPad and my code, but when results are passed to View I get error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List` but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.  I am simply adding return View(data.ToList()).

Comment: View is posted.  I see the first line in the View is @model IEnumerable<TETS_DAL.Project>...which must be why it is looking for same.  But I don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (sorry it's in method syntax):

```
var projects = db.Project.Join(db.Expense, s => s.ProjectKEY, d => d.ProjectKEY,
                   (s, d) => new { Budget = s.Budget, Expenses = d.Amount })
               .Select(a => a.Budget - a.Expenses);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try this in the morning.  In the meantime, how do you display the result in the Project view?  There are other fields in the Project table that need to be shown, too.  Will this affect them?

Comment: Seems it will be works only in case of one to one relationship.

Comment: @Steve You could modify it to use an anonymous object instead.